# How to abstract WebRTC offers?

Tags: javascript, sockets, stream, webrtc, getusermedia

I have run into a strange problem with the abstraction of the offer generation process of WebRTC. It seems as if the incoming ice candidates never reach the null candidate. I have successfully generated offers before using almost the same code but for whatever reason my abstracted version only reaches 12 candidates compared to the regular 20 of my original. This is so strange, it seems the code is pretty much the same but the abstracted one does not work even on the same browser.

Original working code:

```
    var localConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({'iceServers':[{...}]});
    var remoteConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({'iceServers':[{...}]});

    function initMedia(localView, callback){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        var constraints = {audio:true,video:true};
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successStream, errorStream);
        //onSuccess and Error functions
        function successStream(stream){
            window.stream = stream;
            if(window.URL){
                $('#'+localView).attr('src',window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
            } else {
                $('#'+localView).attr('src',stream);
            }
            localConn.addStream(stream);
            remoteConn.addStream(stream);
            console.log('local Stream: '+ stream.id);
            callback();     //-> goes on to create new offer
        }
        function errorStream(error){
            console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
        }
    }

    //function that generates offer and sends it out to a callback
    function newOffer(callback){
        console.log('creating new offer');

        localConn.createOffer(function (sessionDescription){
            localConn.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        }, function(error){
            console.log('Error setting local description: '+error);
        });
        createOffer();
        //gather ICE with a callback to handle/send generated offer
        function createOffer(){
            localConn.onicecandidate = function(iceEvent){
                console.log('gathering local ice');        //ice events fired (20 total)
                //upon gathering all local ice
                if(iceEvent.candidate === null){
                    console.log('local ice gathered');    //success
                    var offer = {'type': localConn.localDescription.type,
                                 'sdp': localConn.localDescription.sdp};
                    offer = JSON.stringify(offer);
                    console.log('offer created');
                    callback(offer);
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

New version with functions for abstraction (not getting null ice candidate)

```
//general rtc vars
var localConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({'iceServers':[{'url':'stun:stun.1.google.com:19302'}]});
var remoteConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({'iceServers':[{'url':'stun:stun.1.google.com:19302'}]});
//var mediaStream;
var channel;

//creates a stream from webcam
//@params function streamHandle(stream)
function initStream(streamHandle){
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    var constraints = {audio:true,video:true};
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successStream, errorStream);
    //onSuccess and Error functions
    function successStream(stream){
        window.stream = stream;
        console.log('TreRTC: Local Stream-'+ stream.id);
        //mediaStream = stream;
        localConn.addStream(stream);    //not sure if these need to be added before
        remoteConn.addStream(stream);   //or if they can be added in the creatOffer(stream) function
        streamHandle(stream);    //gets inserted into createOffer function
    }
    function errorStream(error){
        console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
    }
}

//creates an offer to be sent
//@params Stream stream (from getusermedia)
//@return string offer
function createOffer(stream){
    console.log('TreRTC: Creating Offer');
    //localConn.addStream(stream);    //tried both ways from top and from internal
    //remoteConn.addStream(stream);

    localConn.createOffer(function (sessionDescription){
        localConn.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    }, function(error){
        console.log('Error setting local description: '+error);
    });

    localConn.onicecandidate = function(iceEvt){
        console.log('TreRTC: ICE in');            //ice events firing (12 total)
        if(iceEvt.candidate === null){
            console.log('TreRTC: ICE gathered');    //never reaches to this point...
            var offer = {'type': localConn.localDescription.type,
                         'sdp': localConn.localDescription.sdp};
            offer = JSON.stringify(offer);
            console.log('TreRTC: Offer initialized');
            return offer;    //returns offer as a string
        }    //could also specify a callback
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask what example you based this code on? It's using really old constructs, like the legacy callback API, [a broken createObjectURL pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203036/how-stop-exit-video-in-webrtc-navigator-user-media-javascript/40210033#40210033), and only works with the Chrome browser to boot, because of the webkit prefix (I'm trying to track down old examples to update them).

Comment: stun:stun.1.google.com:19305 is not a stun server. You probably want to test with stun:stun.l.google.com:19305

Answer (score 2):

```
streamHandle(stream);    //gets inserted into createOffer function
```

You probably have a race between your `createOffer` function and your `initStream` function completing, as the two are effectively asynchronous when you count everything they set in motion (hard to tell for sure since you're not showing that code).

If you want to abstract WebRTC, you should look into getting off the old legacy API and instead use RTCPeerConnection's [modern promise-methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer#Example). Promises are superior abstractions to callbacks when it comes to dealing with races exactly like this.

Also consider using the `onnegotiationneeded` callback to trigger negotiation, to solves this (but beware of [bug in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589680/webrtc-double-video-offer-message/40600019#40600019)).

Here's a local connection example (Use [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aynr0k5q/) in Chrome):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(video1.srcObject = stream))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);

pc2.ontrack = e => video2.srcObject = e.streams[0];
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => console.log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="video2" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```